# Disable "cart needs payment" for a specific coupon code in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I need to hide the payment by credit card when I have a specific coupon such as "tcrfam" and when I use any different to this show the payment by card, the idea is that I do not give a coupon of 100% or free and there is no case I ask credit card data.

See the example:
[image: I need]

I tried this code but dont work:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'apply_product_on_coupon');
function apply_product_on_coupon() {
  global $woocommerce;
  $coupon_id = 'tcrfam';
  if(in_array($coupon_id, $woocommerce->cart->get_applied_coupons())){    
    echo "Yes the coupon its inserted dd";
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_payment', '__return_false' );
  }
}
```

I need to use **add_filter ('woocommerce cart needs payment', '__return_false');** within the function as in the code above but I don't know how to do it, can someone give me an idea of how to do it? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that you needs should be in the filter hook directly, like:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_payment', 'filter_cart_needs_payment', 10, 2 );
function filter_cart_needs_payment( $needs_payment, $cart  ) {
    // The targeted coupon code
    $targeted_coupon_code = 'tcrfam';

    if( in_array( $targeted_coupon_code, $cart->get_applied_coupons() ) ) {
        $needs_payment = false;
    }
    return  $needs_payment;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Answer (score -2):

I found this snippet very useful for me, but I've a question ... if the coupon codes for disable the methods payment are more than one? Can I use?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_payment', 'filter_cart_needs_payment', 10, 2 ); function filter_cart_needs_payment( $needs_payment, $cart  ) {
// The targeted coupon code
$targeted_coupon_code = '1code' || '2code';

if( in_array( $targeted_coupon_code, $cart->get_applied_coupons() ) ) {
    $needs_payment = false;
}
return  $needs_payment;
}
```

I tried it, but Woocommerce is not asking me the payment method for every coupon code and not fot only the 2 that I wrote.

Thanks in advance